# An array of views (views that have an UIImage and 3 buttons): Is a custom view/drawRect needed?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, view, uiscrollview, drawrect

Do I need to create a custom view (i.e., a subclass of a UIView where I override drawRect) in order to eventually make an array containing those custom views? Because I ultimately want to make a scrollView that implements page control and displays a number of views (i.e., the array of custom views) on separate pages. The views are just an UIImage above three buttons. And the image for one view is different for each other view (e.g., electronic flash cards).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need a custom view to override `drawRect:` since you are looking to build a collection view using a single image view and three buttons. However it will not hurt to create one so that accessing the sub views can be done via named properties. For example, `customObject.imageView` and `customObject.firstButton`. As a unit it makes sense to create one as it will be messy to keep track of all the image views and buttons you would end up adding to the scroll view otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. Were you saying that I don't need to override drawRect: even if I do a custom view? Because if not that's what I'd prefer to do. I'm just unsure about how to approach creating a custom view without overriding drawRect: (i.e., what other method(s) to use in the custom view).

Comment: Oops! Nevermind. I can just do it from initWithFrame:, correct? :-) Thanks again Deepak

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, mostly you can do it within `initWithFrame:` where you assign frames to each of the subviews and also set their autoresizing masks so that they can respond to change in the frame size of the custom view and adjust themselves accordingly. If you think you need to change your layout based on some parameter then you will have to implement `layoutSubviews`. When you change that parameter, you can simply call `setNeedsLayout`.

Comment: As for [`drawRect:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCDGJHF), the default implementation does nothing. So you can also do nothing if required. Just confirming what you needed.

Comment: Another thought that comes to my mind is that if the three buttons affect the image in the same manner. You should think of putting them in a toolbar instead and based on whichever image is on screen, work on that image. This way you can probably even eliminate a custom view in this case. This is just a suggestion as I don't have proper idea of what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your toolbar suggestion Deepak :-) I think that a toolbar would be ideal in terms of eliminating a custom view. I've restricted this beta app to portrait mode and eventually I'm going to include a small text blurb above or below the image so in this particular case I'm thinking it might be better to just get the custom view out of the way :-) I definitely appreciate your suggestion though - and all your feedback.

Comment: By the way @Deepak in my implementation file for my custom view I did the following: `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect:frame { self = [super initWithFrame:frame]; if (self) { UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds] autorelease]; label.text = @"Test"; [self addSubview:label]; } return self; }` I then added a UIView in Interface Builder and assigned it as my custom view class. The label isn't showing up though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah you're problem is that `initWithCoder:` initializer will be invoked when you use the interface builder.

Comment: Gosh you're awesome. Thanks for the clarification Deepak :-)